# Working out a previous value based on a current value

Tags: word-problem

The question is: In a television quiz show, there are five questions to answer for a monetary reward. Each question is worth twice as much as the previous question. If the last question is worth $64000, what was the first question worth?

Thus far I have worked out that the answer to the question should be $4000 but I don't know how to define the equation that would allow me to arrive at my final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2^4\cdot x=64000$ where $x$ is the worth for first question.

Comment: Thank you for both of your replies.

Answer (score 0):

If each question is worth double the previous one, then each question is worth *half* the next one. So the 4th question is half the 5th, i.e. 32000, the 3rd is worth half of this, i.e. 16000 etc.

If you really wanted an equation *per se*, then if $x$ is the initial question then $x=64000\times(1/2)^4= 4000$, but...

...you don't always need equations in mathematics questions!